# I am facing a issue related to ckeditor Paste from Word Plugin for Internet Explorer

Tags: ckeditor

I have implemented Ck Editor 4.2 with Paste from Word plugin and currently for Internet Explorer ( All 8/9/10/11 ) I am facing a problem as below.

Problem Statement :
If you click on Paste from Word plugin on Firefox/Chrome we get a Ck Editor Dialog to paste content into as a security feature. But for Internet Explorer we are not getting any Dialog from CK Editor which is causing us Browser incompatibility in terms of Paste from Word functionality.

Expected Working of Plugin with Ck Editor for all browsers can be found here : http://ckeditor.com/demo

Can you please help me in fixing this scenario.

Comment: Doesn't the paste button paste content directly? On non IE browsers it's impossible to do that, so CKEditor has to open a dialog. But on IEs it can try to access the clipboard and paste without a dialog or open a dialog if access was not granted. Why is this a problem?

Comment: According to their demo ck editor site the dialog appears for all browsers. On IE if access is not granted then the dialog should appear but it isn't appearing at my end.The content is just directly pasted without providing a dialog if I didn't allow IE to access my clipboard.

Comment: Did you try CKEditor 4.4 (which you should use BTW)? I remember we've fixed some bug, maybe it was it.

Comment: Apologies for replying late,
@Reinmar : I did try using Ck editor 4.4 it resolves the problem but as it is not feasible for me to upgrade now, can we have a work around for the same in order to get it working for Ckeditor 4.2.2.
Please help me with this regard. Thanks for the suggesstions.